# Can fresh pasta sheets be used to assemble a lasagne, then left in the fridge overnight before baking?

Tags: pasta, lasagna

Or will this make them mushy or otherwise degrade them?

I have recently gotten into making fresh pasta, and I want to prep a lasagne the night before. I have done this before with store-bough dried noodles, but I'm not sure if doing this will have a negative effect on fresh, more delicate pasta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done (my mom does it every year for Christmas Eve).

One thing to note, however -- you *must* boil the noodles before assembly -- it doesn't take long, maybe a minute or less (although, work in batches).

This will prevent the noodles from turning into paste as they sit.