# Precooked lasagna with fresh pasta

Tags: lasagna

Can I assemble lasagna the day before I cook it. This is with fresh pasta. I’m worried the pasta will be soggy

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't cook it the day before? 2nd day lasagne I feel would be far preferable. Also see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81009/can-fresh-pasta-sheets-be-used-to-assemble-a-lasagne-then-left-in-the-fridge-ov?rq=1

Comment: Conventional wisdom say to bake it now and reheat the day after; some people will say it tastes better.

Comment: Rather than fresh pasta you can use no boil dry lasagna sheets, these work well wen pre-assembling the day before.

Comment: @GdD - that's a bit like saying "rather than fresh strawberries you can use jam" - the results are just too far different to be adequate substitutes for each other.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree the differences are quite that marked, but that's just my opinion. When you want to pre-assemble lasagna there are trade-offs @Tetsujin, hence why I put this as a comment, not an answer.